# Does Omitted Variable Bias Matter for Prediction?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, bias, omitted-variable-bias

In the context of linear models, I can see why omitted variable bias may matter, as often we are interested in causal effects.

In the context of time series models, we are often interested in prediction. In such a case, wouldn't using biased coefficients on predictors work? Such coefficients would capture the effect of the variable itself, as well as that of omitted variables, and should intuitively lead to similar predictions as the model with unbiased coefficients. I would like to understand if this intuition is correct.

Comment: Generally, even outside the time series context, binary thinking ("X works, Y doesn't work") is inappropriate. Models are not true in reality anyway, so how well prediction works can only be checked on test data outside the sample, and something that is biased in a certain model may still work well in a specific real problem. Also there's more to estimator performance than just bias; sometimes biased with low variance is better than unbiased with larger variance.

Comment: OVB does not "really" matter for prediction.  However, in proposing a causal relationship we are assuming that non-causal correlations might change in time. (but over short term its unlikely...)

Comment: @mkt comes close but not sure if it's exactly what I'm after.

Comment: It would help if you edited your question to focus on what remains unclear after reading that thread.

Comment: Just want to know if my intuition is correct.